# How to create an eclipse theme?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I've seen there are a couple of eclipse color themes around but none seem to be exactly as I want. 
How can I create an eclipse theme myself? I could edit a file but I'm more curious in learning than just tweaking thing I don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example, you can download it to have a look.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064358/eclipsethemes.tar.gz

Comment: Link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the [org.eclipse.ui.themes](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_themes.html) extension point. See the existing extensions for sample.